# Select from results of query?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT Weighings.Member, MIN(Sessions.DateTime) AS FirstDate, MAX(Sessions.DateTime) AS LastDate
FROM Weighings AS Weighings INNER JOIN
     Sessions ON Sessions.SessionGUID = Weighings.Session
WHERE     (Sessions.DateTime >= '01/01/2011')
GROUP BY Weighings.Member
ORDER BY Weighings.Member
```

It returns this:

```
Member | FirstDate | LastDate
Blah   | 01/01/11  | 06/07/11
Blah2  | 02/03/11  | 05/07/11
```

I need to get the value of a cell `Weight_kg` in table `Weighings` for the returned values `FirstDate` and `LastDate` to give results like so:

```
Member | FirstWeight | LastWeight
Blah   | 150Kg       | 60KG
Blah2  | 70Kg        | 72KG
```

I have tried all combinations of things but just can't work it out, any ideas?

**EDIT**

Tables:

```
Sessions
______________________
SessionGUID | DateTime
----------------------
12432524325 | 01/01/11
12432524324 | 01/08/11
12432524323 | 01/15/11
34257473563 | 03/05/11
43634574545 | 06/07/11

Weighings
_____________________________________
Member      | Session     | Weight_kg
-------------------------------------
vffd8fdg87f | 12432524325 | 150
vffd8fdg87f | 12432524324 | 120
vffd8fdg87f | 12432524323 | 110
ddffv89sdv8 | 34257473563 | 124
32878vfdsv8 | 43634574545 | 75
```

Comment: Can you add table schema with some example rows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
;with C as
(
  select W.Member,
         W.Weight_kg,
         row_number() over(partition by W.Member order by S.datetime desc) as rnLast,
         row_number() over(partition by W.Member order by S.datetime asc) as rnFirst
  from Weighings as W
    inner join Sessions as S
      on S.sessionguid = W.Session and
         S.DateTime >= '20110101'
)
select CF.Member,
       CF.Weight_kg as FirstWeight,
       CL.Weight_kg as LastWeigth
from C as CF
  inner join C as CL
    on CF.Member = CL.Member
where CF.rnFirst = 1 and
      CL.rnLast = 1
```

Try here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/118518/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RANK..OVER stmt (works only on SQL 2k5+)

```
select fw.Member, st.Weight, en.Weight
from
(
    select Member, Weight, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Member ORDER BY Weight) rnk
    from Weighings
) st
inner join 
(
    select Member, Weight, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Member ORDER BY WeightDESC) rnk
    from Weighings
) en on en.Member= st.Member and st.rnk = 1 and en.rnk = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two possibilities.

If you want to reuse the first SELECT more times, I'd suggest to sreate temporary table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmpTable` AS SELECT /*the first select*/ ;

/*and then*/

SELECT * FROM `tmpTable` /*the second select from the first select*/
```

If you require the first select only once

```
SELECT first.* 
FROM (SELECT /*the first select*/) AS first
```

Comment: Your not creating a `Temporary` table here.